# How to force a filter on server side to a graphql query?

Tags: graphql, nestjs, prisma-graphql, graphql-tools

Imagine the condition that I have a query called "users" that returns all the users and these users can be associated with one or more companies, so I have a type UserCompanies (I need it because it saves some more information beyond the relation). I'm using Prisma and I need to force a filter that returns only users that are of the same company as the requester. 
I get the information of the company from JWT and need to inject this to the query before sending it to Prisma.

So, query should be like that:

```
query allUsers {
  users {
    name
    id
    status
    email
    userCompanies{
      id
      role
    }
  }
}
```

and on server side, I should transform it to: (user where is ok, just changing args)

```
query allUsers {
  users(where: {
    userCompanies_some: {
      companyId: "companyId-from-jwt"
    }
  }) {
    name
    id
    status
    email
    userCompanies(where: {
      companyId: "companyId-from-jwt"
    }){
      id
      role
    }
  }
}
```

I'm seeing a few resolutions to this, but I don't know if it is the best way:
1 - Using addFragmentToInfo, does the job to put conditions on the query, but if the query has a usercompanies already set, it gives me a conflict. Otherwise, it works fine.
2 - I can use an alias for the query, but after DB result I will need to edit all the results in array to overwrite the result.
3 - don't use info on Prisma and filter in js.
4 - Edit info(4th parameter) of type GraphqlResolveInfo

Comment: I'm sorry, the problem is not how to get the id, is how to edit the received query to that one with filters. But thanks!

Comment: You can check if `addFragmentToInfo` usage is required (userCompanies already requested or not, check if already provided id matches - validation) - no conflict?

Comment: Yes, I can check if is provided, but if it is, it will not be with the where condition. So, when I create it via addFragmentInfo it leads me to the conflict.

Comment: You can pass `companyId` from `users` to `userCompanies` resolver ... where you can check if it exists in parent arg an use it ... combine with existing args (user id)/replace them.... if still not enough enum more precisely use cases?

Comment: The problem is that when using Prisma, you don't need to pass the attributes through resolvers, you can simply pass a info with nested values to fetch and Prisma take care of all. I did end up with a resolution by extending "addFragmentToInfo" of graphql-binding package, I will make some changes and then will post here. Thank you